# How to get corresponding value from max(datetime) with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, pivot-table

MySQL software table:

```
.------------------------------------------------------------.
| id | hostname   | software | version | install_date        |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | computer-a | vim      | 1.00    | 2012-01-04 00:00:00 | 
|------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | computer-a | vim      | 2.00    | 2012-01-05 00:00:00 | 
|------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | computer-b | emacs    | 2.00    | 2012-01-04 00:00:00 | 
|------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | computer-b | emacs    | 1.00    | 2012-01-05 00:00:00 | 
|------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | computer-c | emacs    | 2.00    | 2012-01-05 00:00:00 | 
|------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | computer-c | vim      | 3.00    | 2012-01-05 00:00:00 | 
'------------------------------------------------------------'
```

MySQL query:

```
SELECT 
  hostname,
  MAX(IF(software = 'vim', version, NULL)) AS VIM,
  MAX(IF(software = 'emacs', version, NULL)) AS EMACS
FROM
  software
GROUP BY
  hostname;
```

Result:

```
+-------------+---------+----------+
| hostname    | VIM     | EMACS    |
+-------------+---------+----------+
| computer-a  | 2.0     | NULL     |
+-------------+---------+----------+
| computer-b  | NULL    | 2.0      |
+-------------+---------+----------+
| computer-c  | 3.0     | 2.0      |
+-------------+---------+----------+
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/6247d/3

The problem is that I want to show the versions with the most recent `install_date` for each `software`.  Computer-b should be showing 1.0 for EMACS.  How can the query be changed to accomplish this?

I can change the query to:

```
SELECT 
  hostname,
  MAX(IF(software = 'vim', install_date, NULL)) AS VIM,
  MAX(IF(software = 'emacs', install_date, NULL)) AS EMACS
FROM
  software
GROUP BY
  hostname;
```

This pulls the right install_date but how can I show the corresponding `version`?

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/6247d/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get the `max(install_date)` for each `hostname` and then join that back to your table:

```
select s1.hostname,
  MAX(IF(software = 'vim', version, NULL)) AS VIM,
  MAX(IF(software = 'emacs', version, NULL)) AS EMACS
from software s1
inner join
(
  select max(install_date) i_date,
    hostname
  from software
  group by hostname
) s2
  on s1.install_date = s2.i_date
  and s1.hostname = s2.hostname
group by s1.hostname
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/6247d/10). The result is:

```
|   HOSTNAME |    VIM |  EMACS |
--------------------------------
| computer-a |   2.00 | (null) |
| computer-b | (null) |   1.00 |
| computer-c |   3.00 |   2.00 |
```

You might need to `group by` both the `hostname` and `software` in the subquery if the `software` could have different `install_date`:

```
select s1.hostname,
  MAX(IF(s1.software = 'vim', version, NULL)) AS VIM,
  MAX(IF(s1.software = 'emacs', version, NULL)) AS EMACS
from software s1
inner join
(
  select max(install_date) i_date,
    hostname, software
  from software
  group by hostname, software
) s2
  on s1.install_date = s2.i_date
  and s1.hostname = s2.hostname
group by s1.hostname
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/4db01/6)

Comment: One problem, if the date is changed on one of the computer-c installations, you will only see a version for the most recent installation.  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/4db01/1

Comment: @codybuell then you will alter the subquery to group by both the hostname and software -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/4db01/6 and my edit